# Javascript object gets set to undefined after function that creates it ends

Tags: javascript, createjs

I'm using **create.js**, but whenever the `quequeSetup()` ends queque gets set to undefined, as proven by the `console.log()`'s. Down below is the affected snippet.

```
var queue;

function init() {
    queueSetup();
};

function queueSetup() {
    var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);

    console.log(queue);
    queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    console.log(queue);
    queue.addEventListener("complete", queueLoaded);
    queue.loadManifest([
        {id:"nbckg", src:"images/nbckg.png"},
        {id:"newgame", src:"images/newgame.png"}
    ]);

    console.log(queue);
}

function queueLoaded() { 
    //the following console.log logs undefined
    console.log(queue);

    compName = "NULLCOMPNAME "; 
    stage = new createjs.Stage("MyCanvas");

    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

    //LOAD MAINMANU

    // loadMainMenu();
    initUI();
}
```

Comment: Remove the var statement before the queue variable definition in the queueSetup function.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'm not familiar with createjs, but in `queueSetup()`, the `var queue` creates a new variable named `queue` scoped to the function.  To reference the `queue` variable outside the function, leave out the `var`.

Answer (score 0):

As others have mentioned, you're trying to access a variable that's not a global variable. It's only available inside the `queueSetup` function. You could just declare it `window.queue` and be done with it, but rather than doing that, it's better to return it and pass it on to the `queueLoad` function.

```
function init() {
   queueSetup();
};

function queueSetup() {
    var queue = new createjs.LoadQueue(false);

    console.log(queue);
    queue.installPlugin(createjs.Sound);
    console.log(queue);
    queue.addEventListener("complete", function() {
         queueLoaded(queue); // pass the queue variable to our queueLoaded function
    });
    queue.loadManifest([
        {id:"nbckg", src:"images/nbckg.png"},
        {id:"newgame", src:"images/newgame.png"}
    ]);

    console.log(queue);
    return queue;
}

function queueLoaded(queue) { // add the variable as an argument
    //the following console.log logs undefined
    console.log(queue);

    compName = "NULLCOMPNAME "; 
    stage = new createjs.Stage("MyCanvas");

    createjs.Ticker.addEventListener("tick", tick);

    //LOAD MAINMANU

    // loadMainMenu();
    initUI();
}
```

Comment: The original code had a `queue` variable in the scope of the script, hidden by another `queue` variable in the `queueSetup()` scope. While you suggest to have a `queue` variable in the global scope, which I think is a bad practice. Better remove the `var` keyword in `queueSetup()` like Pitaj suggested.

Comment: Yeah, definitely. Let me add back that `var`